# is Google App Engine-MapReduce my best bet for a massively parallel solution in a cloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, parallel-processing

Is Google App Engine-MapReduce my best bet for a massively parallel solution in a cloud?  My problem takes hours multi-threaded on a 4 core PC.  I'd say 600 minutes might do.  I would prefer 1000 servers get it done in 36 seconds.  Switching from 4 core threading to 1000 server processing is eminently doable in my app.  In fact, I can already send 1000 small jobs to 4 cores but it's not going to get done sooner than 4 big jobs to 4 cores given that I still have only 4 cores.  (My dataset is small so Map-Reduce, which was designed for large datasets, might have a different sweet-spot than my type of compute-bound problem.)

I think I can get this done if I have 1000 simultaneous URL fetches but as you may know Google limits at 10 requests.  It seems Google is actively discouraging outsiders from putting massively parallel solutions on their infrastructure.

I started looking into Google App Engine because upon deployment there will be very few users and it appeared App Engine has fine-grained costs - a feature I really like.  My impression was that Amazon EC2 would be more work but also that costs were more likely to be chunky.  Given that I'm a home-based business, I don't want to pay anything more than a nominal amount when in the early months I don't expect a lot of visitors to my website.  May be they will never visit.

In general, where do people turn to for massively parallel (compute-bound) problems that ought to be served by a cloud?

Comment: Maybe you should describe the algorithm you want to run and then we might be able to tell you whether it is a mapreducable problem or not.

Answer (score 2):

For compute bound tasks, EC2 is often better than App Engine.  App Engine is focused on serving web requests, not pure number crunching.  It is not designed to go from 0 requests this minute to 1000 requests the next minute and back to 0 requests the minute after that.  In fact, one of its features is that you generally don't need explicit control over how many instances are running at once.   Also, long running jobs are not possible, though for many tasks you can use Task Queues to chain jobs together.  I think the current limit on background tasks is 10 minutes.

EC2 does have a super low tier of service that you can get for [free](http://aws.amazon.com/free/). EC2 lets you explicitly bring servers up and down, but I think the smallest increment you can pay for is 1 hour.

Of course, if you want to literally run your job on 1000 servers, neither app engine nor EC2 will likely let you do that for free.  Both are very elastic/adaptive, but bringing 1000 servers up for 30 seconds of work is not very economical for them.  On App Engine you will likely run up against an hourly or daily quota before you had 1000 simultaneous instances running.  On EC2, you generally pay by the server instance.  So you would be paying for 1000 hours of instance time.  Of course, one of Amazon's High CPU instances might be much more powerful than your PC, so maybe you'd only need a 100 or so.  or maybe you could compromise and have only 20 instances running at a time, meaning it takes a few minutes to finish your computation, but you don't go broke.

Comment: I disagree that App Engine is not designed to go from 0 requests to 1000 and back to 0 in a minute.  App Engine does that for browsers but Google decided not to allow it for URL fetches from the app itself.

Comment: I am not aiming to do anything for free.  1000 servers for 36 seconds = $1 at a rate of $0.10 per server-hour on App Engine.  1000 server instances for a minimum of an hour, in order to do 36 seconds of work, is just wasteful.  Also instantiating servers takes time; perhaps more time than users would be willing to wait.  If so, then servers would have to be kept running continually (possibly just fewer of them when higher user population time zones go to sleep).  It looks like EC2 can only be practical for apps have a large number of users.

Comment: instantiating new instances on app engine takes time just like it does on ec2.  Are you saying you have seen an App Engine app go from 1 running instance to 1000 running instances and then back to 0 all within a minute?  That does not jive with my understanding of how app engine scaling works.  If you wanted to see how fast you could get the instances to spin up, you should be able to work around the limit of 10 simultaneous url fetches - just have your first handler fetch another url 10 times (in async mode), and have each of those fetch yet another url 10 times (in async mode), and so on.

Comment: I suggest we already know GAE can supply service instances (and by extension server instances) pretty quickly because it faces the public and the public, while not in perfect unison, are coordinated and at the least, cannot be predicted.  It may be there's just a lot of excess capacity given the popularity of Google search.  The fetch limit is 10 per app (not per handler).

Comment: oops.  I didn't notice the limit on async calls was per app.  Have you explored using the task queue? Paid apps can have 100 queues, with 50 task invocations per second per queue.  That sounds good enough in theory , but I've never tried to pump a bajillion tasks through at once, so I don't know how fast they would all get processed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Amazon's Elastic MapReduce? http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/

With App Engine you should also investigate the task queues. If you already know how to split the big problem into many small ones, you could create one task that takes in the big problem and then creates 1000 (or 10.000) subtasks to tackle the smaller problems. And after that collect the results in one task, if needed.

Individual tasks can run up to 10 minutes before they are terminated, which makes them a little bit easier to use for computing tasks than regular requests.